# SonarQube Server Startig multiple sqlplus processes on server

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

SonarQube version = 6.0 with oracle 11g.

I see number of sqlplus processes being started by sonarqube server on the host. Like 1  0 Jul31 ?        00:00:00 sqlplus -S                                                      @/tmp/32766.sql

These processes don't end and causing swap memory issue on the host.

Can anyone suggest what these processes are?

Comment: What's your driver version?

Comment: Oracle JDBC driver 11.2.0.1.0

Comment: It's quite strange to have those processes launched by SonarQube with the JDBC driver, I'm not aware of such behaviour with the JDBC driver. Do you confirm that the parent process is SonarQube ? Can you post the content of /tmp/32766.sql ?

Comment: set newpage 0
set space 0
set linesize 32767
set pagesize 0
set echo off
set feedback off
set verify off
set heading off
set markup html off spool off
set trim on
set wrap off

define user = 'SONAR'
define tbsp = 'SONAR_DA'
define quot = '*'

select tq.username, tq.tablespace_name, trunc(tq.bytes/1024/1024) bytes, trunc(decode(tq.max_bytes, -1, -1, tq.max_bytes/1024/1024)) max_bytes,
       sum(df.bytes)/1024/1024 tbsp_mbytes, sum(decode(df.maxbytes, 0, df.bytes, df.maxbytes))/1024/1024 tbsp_max_mbytes
from dba_ts_quotas tq, dba_data_files df

Comment: where  df.tablespace_name = tq.tablespace_name
and    regexp_like(tq.tablespace_name, nvl('&tbsp', '*'), 'i')
and    regexp_like(tq.username, nvl('&user', '*'), 'i')
and    regexp_like(to_char(tq.max_bytes), nvl('&quot', '*'), 'i')
and    tq.tablespace_name not in ('SYSTEM','SYSAUX')
group by tq.username, tq.tablespace_name, trunc(tq.bytes/1024/1024), trunc(decode(tq.max_bytes, -1, -1, tq.max_bytes/1024/1024))
order by username;

quit

Comment: Thanks Jayesh, 
So I do confirm that those requests are not sent by SonarQube (at least directly). 
I did not find any reference of such behaviour. Can you check who is the parent process of those commands.